# flex element keeping a row as auto width ( shrink with content ) is possible?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.first{
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
}

.second{
  background-color: gray;
  color: yellow;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="first">full width</div>
  <div class="second">
  inline-block
  </div>
```

I do not want to "second" div occupied with 100%. i want to keep it as like "inline-block" the width should extended until the content available. is it possible to do with flex?

thanks in advance

Comment: width: fit-content; for .second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `align-self` to limit flex-items within flexbox.

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.first{
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
}

.second{
  background-color: gray;
  color: yellow;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">full width</div>
  <div class="second">
    inline-block
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to shrink the border as well in that case remove a border from parent and add `.container * {
    border:1px solid red;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-right: auto` to `.second` class.

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.first{
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
}

.second{
  background-color: gray;
  color: yellow;
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">full width</div>
  <div class="second">
  inline-block
  </div>
```